# Postgresql 42883 error code with encrypt function

Tags: postgresql, encryption

Ok, the thing is that I'm doing a login controller on my database. Part of it is this function to create users that goes like this:

```
create or replace function crear_usuario(par_usuario varchar,par_clave text,
    par_nombre varchar,par_correo varchar) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
    existe int;
    clave_cript bytea;
    llave text;
BEGIN
    /* 0:Insertado con exito | 1:Usuario ya registrado*/
    select into existe count(id) from usuarios where usuario=$1;
    if existe=0 then
        select into llave 'encrypt key';
        select into clave_cript encrypt(llave,$2,'3des');
        insert into usuarios (usuario,clave,nombre,correo) values ($1,clave_cript,$3,$4);
    end if;
    RETURN existe;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql  RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT ;
```

The error is showing in the line with the encrypt function, which I tested on it's own in the cli.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[Looking up](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/errcodes-appendix.html) the error number clearly tells you that the function `encrypt`() isn't found.

Its possible that

- That `encrypt`() function is provided by an extension that you forgot to do install on that database (via `CREATE EXTENSION`)
- If `encrypt`() is a custom function, probably some other script needs to run first that creates that function before this function.

Comment: It's a extension actually and it's created. I also test de encrypt() function by itself and works fine....

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mji2goyb00gjmkg/Captura%20de%20pantalla%202016-02-19%2019.18.59.png?dl=1

Here's a screenshoot of the error

Comment: Do I need any special permission to use the 'encrypt' function to use in another function?? maybe there was something missing in the creation of the extension?? I also test it on a manual insert and it was ok!!